# Configure promtail 2.0 to read the files .log

Tags: linux, logging, centos, grafana, grafana-loki

Since I've updated to promtail 2.0, I'm unable to read the content of a log file in loki.

config-promtail.yml

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://192.168.1.103:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: manuallog
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - 192.168.1.103
        labels:
          job: tomcat
          host: 192.168.1.103
          path: /opt/error.log
```

I've also tried to use a different configuration in the scrape config, but with no luck:

```
  - job_name: varlog
journal:
  max_age: 12h
  labels:
    filename: /opt/error.log
    path: /opt/error.log
```

The error.log is not empty:

```
    # cat /opt/error.log
Disconnected from localhost
```

The Promtail version - 2.0

```
    ./promtail-linux-amd64 --version
promtail, version 2.0.0 (branch: HEAD, revision: 6978ee5d)
  build user:       root@2645337e4e98
  build date:       2020-10-26T15:54:56Z
  go version:       go1.14.2
  platform:         linux/amd64
```

Any clue? Am I doing anything wrong?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try replace:

```
path: /opt/error.log
```

To:

```
__path__: /opt/error.log
```

Comment: I tried to do that. Now on Loki Grafana I can see a label "filename". But this label is linked to loki.service. Watching the log labels i can see:
filename error.log
unit loki.service

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you only specified:

```
journal.lables.path: /opt/error.log
```

which will only add a label to scraped log entries.

You forgot to specify:

```
journal.path: /opt/error.log
```

which will tell Promtail where to find those logs to tail.

==========================================================

Here is my working Promtail 2.1 journal scraping config.

```
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: journal
        pipeline_stages:
          - drop:
              expression: ".*something-redudant.*"
        journal:
          path: /var/log/journal
          max_age: 12h
          labels:
            job: systemd-journal
        relabel_configs:
          - source_labels: ['__journal__systemd_unit']
            target_label: 'unit'
          - source_labels: ['__journal__hostname']
            target_label: 'hostname'
```